# USPS RateV4 - Invalid container type

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, api, usps

I am in the process of upgrading USPS RateV3 API to RateV4. I have done everything specified in the docs. I have my container types like:

```
 <Service>ONLINE</Service>
 <Container>FLAT RATE ENVELOPE, FLAT RATE BOX, VARIABLE</Container>
```

Similarly for Size:

```
 <Size>REGULAR, LARGE</Size>
```

This is all working perfectly in RateV3 but not working in RateV4. It only works when the container type is "VARIABLE" and Size is "REGULAR". Other than this I am getting this error:

`FLAT RATE ENVELOPE is an invalid container type for a REGULAR package and ONLINE service.`

This request is working correctly:

```
<RateV4Request USERID="">
    <Package ID="0">
        <Service>ONLINE</Service>
        <ZipOrigination>1234</ZipOrigination>
        <ZipDestination>5678</ZipDestination>
        <Pounds>1</Pounds>
        <Ounces>0.0</Ounces>
        <Container>VARIABLE</Container>
        <Size>REGULAR</Size>
        <Machinable>true</Machinable>
    </Package>
</RateV4Request>
```

This is not working and results in invalid container type error:

```
<RateV4Request USERID="">
    <Package ID="0">
        <Service>ONLINE</Service>
        <ZipOrigination>1234</ZipOrigination>
        <ZipDestination>5678</ZipDestination>
        <Pounds>1</Pounds>
        <Ounces>0.0</Ounces>
        <Container>FLAT RATE ENVELOPE</Container>
        <Size>REGULAR</Size>
        <Machinable>true</Machinable>
    </Package>
</RateV4Request>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for formatting @pixelmeow :)

Comment: I was able to make it work by checking if the container type is any of FLAT RATE ENVELOPE, FLAT RATE BOX set it to "VARIABLE" before sending the request to API. Now it is working perfect for "REGULAR" size packages but not working for "LARGE" size package. I am getting the following error for LARGE size package:  
**Error Information: According to the dimensions entered, your package is too large to be mailed**.


Any thoughts???